# JQuery remove spaces between two different tags

Tags: jquery, css

### Environment

JQuery: 1.11.3

### Question

```html
<span class="inline">...</span>
"&nbsp;&nbsp;"
<span class="inline">...</span>
"&nbsp;&nbsp;"
```

I hava a `<span>` tag wrapped in two `<span>` tags, each internal `<span>` tag is followed by `"&nbsp;&nbsp;"`

I hope to remove `"&nbsp;&nbsp;"`

If text too longer `"&nbsp;&nbsp;"` will turn into `<br>` effect.

#### Error

```
longer text1

longer text2
```

#### Expected effect

```
longer text1
longer text2
```

Internal  tags have a class.

```css
.inline {
    display: inline-block !important;
}
```

It is also possible to solve the effect

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: _"If text too longer "&nbsp;&nbsp;" will turn into <br> effect."_ - that probably has rather less to do with the non-breaking spaces, and more with `display: inline-block`.

Comment: Why is this tagged with jquery?

Answer (score -1):

Try This One :

```html
<span style="display:block;">longer &nbsp;&nbsp; text1</span>
<span style="display:block;">longer &nbsp;&nbsp; text2</span>
```